# routerLink volver atrás

Tags: angular, angular-router

tengo un routerLink y necesito que al hacer click me vuelva atrás como podría hacer esto?

```
<a routerLink="./">
    <button mat-raised-button>Volver</button>
</a>
```

Esto no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo solucione con `*ngIf`

Comment: Y eso cómo? O.o

Answer (score 3):

Esto es lo que estabas buscando en realidad:

HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="goBack()">Volver</button>
```

.TS:

```
goBack() {
this.router.navigate(['/tuRuta']);
}
```

Tienes que importar Router desde '@angular/router' y agregarlo al constructor para poder instanciarlo así

```
constructor( private router: Router ) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta usando el service **Location** de la siguiente manera

```
 import { Location } from '@angular/common';

 constructor(private _location: Location) {}

 goBack(){
   this._location.back();
 }

 <button mat-raised-button (click)="goBack()">Volver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal rafa puedes especificar a la ruta que quieres volver con el pleca y la ruta.

```
<a routerLink="/home">
<button mat-raised-button>Volver</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Buenas prueba así.

```
<a routerLink="..">
<button mat-raised-button>Volver</button>
</a>
```

Comment: queva :/ no funciona